# Страница сайта как будто немного сдвинута влево на мобильный устройствах

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, вёрстка, css

Из-за чего страница сайта может быть как будто немного сдвинута влево на мобильный устройствах так, что справа пустое пространство образуется в 10-20 px. На десктопе всё нормально отображается!

Answer (score 1):

Из-за отсутствия вот этого мета тэга:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
```